# Vaadin non-mandatory login

Tags: authentication, vaadin, web-frontend

I am experienced Java backend developer, but an absolute novice with front-end and now I am trying to do web app with Vaadin for the first time in my life.

I got an idea how to create a main view but stumbled on login implementation.
In my application login is not mandatory. If user is not logging in it shall allow him to view the data in grid format and by clicking on a record get some additional details.
If user wants more functionality he is suppose to login and based on the user credentials there should be some changes in the grid view and some additional buttons shall appear, that will allow creating new entries and do something else.

I did go through the Vaadin tutorial, but it only explains what was written in ***their*** application, but doesn't teach how to do other things. I tried to find some clues in components documentation and Javadoc, but got lost there.

If someone can give me some tips on where to start digging, I will appreciate greatly.

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin uses Spring Security.
You can use annotations to secure a whole view. But if you want to change certain parts of the view, you must do that programmatically.

Spring Security provides the `SecurityContextHolder` class to access the logged in user and the roles.

To check if the user has a certain role you can do

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (auth != null && auth.getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getAuthority().equals("ADMIN"))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, Vaadin *optionally* uses Spring Security. Some of us use Vaadin without Spring.

Comment: @BasilBourque sure! As the OP didn't tell what he uses I assumed that he uses Spring Boot